# How can I get the FileInfo of all files in a folder with GetFile()?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I don't know what's my mistake.

```
FileInfo[] FileInformation = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(textBoxPath.Text);  
for (int i = 0; i <= FileInformation.Length; i++)
{
    File.Move(FileInformation[i].DirectoryName, FileInformation[i].Directory + "File" + i);
}
```

Visual Studio says that here is the error:

> System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(textBoxPath.Text);

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo) is not a static class (you mixed it with [`Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory) which exposes static methods). Thus you should create instance of it:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxPath.Text);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
```

Also I suggest you to use `Path.Combine` for generating new file path and `FileInfo.MoveTo` method, which don't require source directory name:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    FileInfo file = files[i];
    string destination = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, "File", i.ToString());
    file.MoveTo(destination);
}
```

---

One more thought – if you don't need any additional info about files, besides names, then you can get file names only, without `FileInfo` objects creation. Use static methods of `Directory` and `File` classes. That will be more efficient:

```
string sourceDir = @"D:\Downloads";
        
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    string fileName = files[i];
    var destination = Path.Combine(sourceDir, "File", i.ToString());
    File.Move(fileName, destination);             
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(textBoxPath.Text);
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileInformations = dir.GetFiles();  
    for (int i = 0; i <= fileInformations.Length; i++)
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(fileInformations[i].DirectoryName, System.IO.Path.Combine(FileInformation[i].Directory, "File" + i));
    }
```

**EDIT:**
renamed your `FileInformation` to the properway to write local variable names `fileInformations`. Used `Path.Combine` to combine paths and filename instead of using string combination, as this will take care of missing / and other path issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Y);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
       //do whatever with the file
    }
}
```