# How to get filename, size, and last modified fileinfo of all files in folder into gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I know how to look into folders with Directory.GetFiles, and how to use FileInfo for file information, but I can't figure out how to put these concepts together.
When I looked up the Directory class I could only get filenames so I'm stuck, I can only get the gridview to make a 1 dimensional table but I need 3 columns for the info stated in title.
 I'm new to asp.net/c# I'm sorry if the answer is right in my face. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
//If there are any files in the folder, get info of file
```

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Button Clicked!!!";

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(folderpath).Length > 0)
{
    String name = FileUpload1.FileName;
    //provide file path, the name of file, then grab info of file
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(folderpath + FileUpload1.FileName);
    //testing if we retrieved info 
    Label1.Text = ("Name :" + file.Name + "<BR/>" + "Size :" + file.Length + "<BR/>" + "Modified :" + file.LastWriteTime + "<BR/>");

    string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderpath, "*");
    grdFile.DataSource = allfiles;
    grdFile.DataBind();
}
```

}

The code snippet is more me showing my current understanding, not necessarily a proper attempt at what I am trying to do.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620076/how-can-i-get-the-fileinfo-of-all-files-in-a-folder-with-getfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the files from a directory and show the properies you want in the GridView.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/"));
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();

GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

ASPX code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="System.IO.FileInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.Name %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# string.Format("{0:N1}", (decimal)Item.Length / 1024) %> kb
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modified">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.LastWriteTime.ToLongDateString() %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a odd request, as you want to get Filesystem Information in a Web Server context. As they are mostly always on, WebServers tend to be the most interesting targets for hacking. In order to compensate for that, they are usually given a seperate user with some of the most restrictive rights possible: Read rights on the Programm and Content Directory. Maybe sometimes the right to write some subfolder of the Content directory for caching purposes, but even that is not guaranteed.

As for the actuall code: Currently you are retrieving the File Names/Full File paths. That is all the inforamtion that can be stored in a `string[]`. You can use them to create the [FilInfo instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) that will give you the remaining information.

You may have to create a Custom Class, struct or Tupple to hold the data for each file. Then create a List of that type. Itterate over the list of filenames and annd new instances.